# How can I use input from a TextBox in a PowerQuery Formula?

Tags: excel, powerquery, vba

I would like to use a PowerQuery Formula which includes input from a text box like

```
Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://thesite.com/api/widgets",
              [Query=[name=TextBoxName.Text]]))
```

But I get this error

```
Expression.Error: The import TextBoxName.Text matches no exports. Did
 you miss a module reference?
```

How do I use **TextBoxName.Text** as a parameter in my query?

Answer (score 4):

Does it have to be a text box? Put the value in an Excel table instead and call that table "Parameters".

[image]

Then write a function that reads the parameters in the table.

```
(ParameterName as text) =>
let
   ParamSource = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Parameters"]}[Content],
   ParamRow = Table.SelectRows(ParamSource, each ([Parameter] ParameterName)),
   Value=
      if Table.IsEmpty(ParamRow)=true
      then null
      else Record.Field(ParamRow{0},"Value")
in
   Value
```

Give that function the name fnGetParameter and load it.

Now you can use this function in another query to get the value of any parameter in the table like this:

```
let
   MyQuery = fnGetParameter("JSONQuery"),
   Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://thesite.com/api/widgets",
              [Query=[name=MyQuery]]))
```

Credit goes to Ken Puls who describes this technique on [his blog](http://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2014/11/26/building-a-parameter-table-for-power-query/) and also in his book "M is for (Data) Monkey".

Comment: This is what I ended up using. Had my TextBox update a cell in another sheet on text changed. Upvote for workaround.